# How to fix port error when creating Django backend service on Google Cloud Run?

Tags: mysql, django, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, port

I have a Django REST backend image in which I tried to create a service for it on Google Cloud Run. In the Google Cloud Run, I set the port to 6000, and when I tried to create it, it showed these errors:

> RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '35.226.227.51' (115)")

> The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=6000 environment variable.

> Default STARTUP TCP probe failed 1 time consecutively for container "backend" on port 6000. The instance was not started.

The last 2 layers on the Dockerfile of my backend are:

```
EXPOSE 6000

CMD python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:6000
```

I am not sure how to fix this for this is my first time trying to deploy a website.

For the database error, I have checked the database credentials and configured my Django settings.py to connect to my Google Cloud SQL, MySQL instance with the public IP address as shown and made sure the configuration is correct, but not really sure why it is showing that error.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Google Cloud has a lot of products so saying you're deploying in it is not helpful. What are you using? A VM? Cloud Run? Also you may need to provide more details, where is the DB? Did you configure the firewall?

Comment: @Puteri I'm deploying the backend using Google Cloud Run and the database is deployed on Google Cloud SQL. For the firewall, I'm not really well-versed with it, but I'll also look onto that. Thanks for that, I didn't notice it, will edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Have you reviewed https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run?

Comment: Is your database error blocking? I mean, if the database connection fail, does the container start fail? If so, your error is normal, fix your database error it will fix your instance start (and serving port) error

Comment: I have now fixed it and deployed my website. What I did was I set the database host on my settings.py to /cloudsql/instance-connection-name and also changed the port from 6000 to 9000 (I looked it up and found out that some browsers block port 6000 specifically). Thank you for all the information and help :)!

Comment: From the above comment, I assume that your problem has been solved. Can you share your solution as an answer so that it will help others too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has now been solved and here's what I did:

To solve for the database connection error, I configured my settings.py as such:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': '/cloudsql/<instance connection name>',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '<root password>',
        'NAME': '<database name>',
    }
}
```

And to solve the port errors, I changed my port from 6000 to 9000 (I found out that some browsers block port 6000 specifically), and changed the last 2 lines of my Dockerfile from this:

```
EXPOSE 6000

CMD python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:6000
```

To this:

```
CMD python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9000
```